# How to make MySQL table records into a PHP parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve the value from radio button which fetch from a while looping , where name attribute is `$row['id_question']`, then I want to count the value, so I would need `array_count_value()`, I have no idea how to change this `$row['id_question']` into parameter in `array_count_value()`.

I'm getting the error:

> Undefined index: answer in
>   &
>   array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

I tried to make that into a variable 
`$answer = $_POST['answer']`;

but I don't think it'll work (be valid)

This is the code:

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<br/>" . $row['question'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "
        <label class='radio-inline'><span>YES</span>
            <input type='radio' class='form-check-label' name= 'answer[".$row['id_question']."]' checked value='1'/>
        </label>
        <label class='radio-inline'><span>NO</span>
            <input type='radio' class='form-check-label' name= 'answer[".$row['id_question']."]' checked value='2'/>
        </label>
        ";
    }
    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) ){
        print_r($answer); 
    }
    print_r(array_count_values($answer));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Seems like you have a fair way to go, before this will work. :-/

I think I would start by printing out the `$row`s - ensuring that you actually get something inside that `while`-loop.

And remember, to instantiate a variable before the while-loop, and then populate it inside the while-loop. Something like this:

```
<?php
$answer = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // What happens here? :-)
    echo "<pre";
    print_r( $row );
    echo "<pre";

    echo "<br/>" . $row['question'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "
    <label class='radio-inline'><span>YES</span>
        <input type='radio' class='form-check-label' name= 'answer[".$row['id_question']."]' checked value='1'/>
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'><span>NO</span>
        <input type='radio' class='form-check-label' name= 'answer[".$row['id_question']."]' checked value='2'/>
    </label>
    ";
}

$answer = $_POST['answer'];

// FALLBACK SO IT DOESN'T CRASH AND BURN
if( ! $answer ){
  echo '$answer was null again! I'll save you, by assigning it an empty array. :-) ';
  $answer = []; 
}
// END OF FALLBACK

if (isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    print_r($answer); 
}
print_r(array_count_values($answer));
?>
```

---

And the error you're getting ( 'Undefined index: answer in'... ) - that's because `$_POST['answer']` isn't defined, - and therefore `$answer` will be set to null. And [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) expects an array as an input, - it cannot be null.

I hope this helps. :-)

Comment: thanks for your answer to my question, i've followed your advice but i still get the warning about undefined index and the printed about the index still null

Comment: Hmm... As stated, - based on what you're writing and your code, then it seems like that you're pretty far away from something that will work. :-/